# -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% doesn't work on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, email, fonts

I'm developing my own framework for responsive emails.
I have an issue with font size on iPhone that gets way too big when the phone is in landscape mode. I tried  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; as suggested in other topics, but it seems that the solutions that I've found don't work for me. I am testing my framework with Email On Acid.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="email-background">
        <div class="email-container">
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce non diam consectetur, tempor sapien id, 
semper mi.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
}

p {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 20px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I tried to recreate your example and I was able to get it to work. Here is my code i tested it on my iPhone and it looked normal to me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <style type="text/css">


p {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto <!-- I changed it to auto and moved it -->
                                   <!-- to the paragraph tag.             -->
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="email-background">
        <div class="email-container">
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce non diam consectetur, tempor sapien id, 
semper mi.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work with Email On Acid (I don't have an iPhone right now to check). Have you tried with the Gmail app or with the native mail app? 'Cause it works in Gmail, but not in the mailbox app. I convert the css to inline style.